# MySql partial match based on part of the query code

Tags: mysql, sql, wildcard

In MySql, is there any way of getting a partial match if you use something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%orange llp%';
```

And the output to be something like:

```
+-----------------+
| name            | 
+-----------------+
| Orange          |
| Telecomm Orange |
| Orange SA       | 
| Orange LLP      | 
+-----------------+
```

So even if the query is not an exact string to get matches based on just part of it?
Hopefully, this makes sense.

EDIT: I'm using this with a nodejs & express backend so the query will be done automatically by the backend

Comment: I used this in my search function ```SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` LIKE '%$input%'```. $input is the input the user does to search

Comment: Are you using any application programming language here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, javascript

Comment: Oh, I see you use JavaScript, just plain JavaScript or any extra frameworks such as Node or React? @tritomit then I can change my answer accordingly.

Comment: @FUZIION I use node js with express framework and mysql package. sorry I should've mention this in the original post.

Comment: No problem, try the SQL query from my answer, it might be a syntax issue

Comment: What does that query do thats not desirable ?

Comment: '%orange llp%' will get only the entry Orange LLP. I would like to get all entries that have 'orange' in the name, or LLP etc.

Comment: Then you have to split your search into multiple "words" and then add a WHERE LIKE '%word%' condition for each. Someone posted an answer with this solution but in PHP below.

Comment: @tritomit your last comment completely changes your question! It is not nice adding new conditions to a question after receiving an answer that satisfies the original question! Not to mention the fact that your dditional requurement is only in a comment, not in the question!

Comment: Its fine. I added OP's wishes to the answer

Comment: @Shadow I thought the whole point of a question and implicitly a problem that you have is to find an answer and a solution for it one way or the other. I might've altered somehow the original meaning of the question but this is just because I, myself couldn't understand exactly the issue that I had and maybe couldn't find the right words to describe it, but after a couple of ideas that resulted from this thread I've managed to find out thus finding an answer. Sorry but your statement _adding new conditions to a question_ makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @tritomit apparently you are not well-versed in SO customs! See answers to the following question on how you should have handled this situation: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303914/realized-i-posted-wrong-question The main problem is: the accepted answer does not answer the question you asked up there.

Comment: understood! I will try to change this, if not I will take care in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you updated that you are not using php se below

```
var searchQuery = "orange llp";
var splitQuery = searchQuery.split(" ");
var sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ( name";
for(i = 0; i < splitQuery.length; i++){
  var query = splitQuery[i];
  sqlQuery += " LIKE '%" + query + "%' OR name ";
}
sqlQuery += " LIKE '%" + searchQuery + "%' )";

//Now run your query like below
con.query(sqlQuery);
```

Your output query will look like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ( name LIKE '%orange%' OR name  LIKE '%llp%' OR name  LIKE '%orange llp%' )
```

Use this class [php search controller](https://github.com/peterujah/php-search-controller) for php version

```
 $searchQuery = "orange llp";
 $search = new SearchController(SearchController::OR);
 $search->setOperators(SearchController::HAVE_ANY_QUERY);
 $search->setQuery($searchQuery)->split();
 $search->setParameter(array('name', /*more columns to search on*/));

 $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM table {$search->getQuery()}";
```

You can also add other clues

```
$sqlQuery = "
  SELECT * FROM table {$search->getQuery()}
  AND id = anything else
";
```

Comment: I did this, and it works, I just changed your `for` loop with a HOF `forEach()` like `splitQuery.forEach(queryWord => {query += " LIKE '%" + queryWord + "%' OR name"
  })` just to be cleaner

Comment: Am glad it worked

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you do not have any `'s around your table name and column name, and you don't order the output (no idea if this is a requirement, but it works for me so..)

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` LIKE '%orange llp%' ORDER BY `id`;
```

If you want to select multiple values, try it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE `name` LIKE '%word1%'
  OR `name` LIKE '%word2%'
  OR `name` LIKE '%word3%'
ORDER BY `id`;
```

Image:
[image]

I just tested this within a random database in my `phpmyadmin` and it functioned as expected.

```
SELECT * FROM `adminnotification_inbox` WHERE `description` LIKE '%to imp%' ORDER BY `notification_id`;
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this works but please see my comment above

Comment: Updating answer with that!

Comment: Your  second example query titled `try it like this` will not return any result.

Comment: Yes I did it wrong, it was supposed to be OR, that way it searches for the value's induvidually. I edited my post

Comment: this works, but I will mark @Peter 's answer as correct since I'm using nodejs and this query will be done by it.